# I am sending picture file from pc to android phone both are connected to same WLAN via socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to send pic from pc to android phone I have problem in sending pic. I am posting code of java application that is sending picture here.

```
 public void send(OutputStream os) throws Exception{
  // sendfile
  File myFile = new File ("E:\\a.png");
  System.out.println("the file is read");
  byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()+1];
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  System.out.println("Sending...");
  os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  os.flush();
  }
```

above code just write file on port.

here is android code that will actually receive that file. The loop start and does not exit. Connection to port is correct and I can send and reeve string

```
     public Bitmap receiveFile(InputStream is) throws Exception{
     String baseDir =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "myFile.png";
        String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
      int filesize=6022386;
      int bytesRead;
      int current = 0;
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;


        do {
           bytesRead =
              is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
           if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;

        } while(bytesRead != -1);

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);  
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        return null;
  }
```

kindly suggest any other way of sharing picture as well

Answer (score 0):

This line is the issue:

```
       if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
```

When you receive `0` bytes from a TCP socket, it means the other side has closed the connection, so there's nothing more to read. Exit your loop at that point.

Comment: because I am not sure what you actually mean and what sort of change you suggested

Comment: Add explicit check for `bytesRead` being zero and exit the loop on that.

Comment: if ( is.available()==0)
               break;
        I used above check it works fine and reads all the bytes but file is croupted